# How to add element in another list which are not similar?

Tags: dart

1. First array `List<String> first=['101','102','103','104','105'];`
2. Second array `List<String> first=['101','102','103'];`

> How to compare two lists and add an unmatched element in another array

1. output `List<String> first=['104,'105];`

Answer (score 2):

You can copy paste run full code to DartPad

```
void main() {
  List<String> first=['101','102','103','104','105'];
  List<String> second=['101','102','103'];

  List<String> result = [];

  first.forEach((firstElement) { 
                   if (!second.contains(firstElement)){
                     result.add(firstElement);
                   }
                 }
               ); 

  print(result.toString());

}
```

output

```
[104, 105]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `difference()` provided for `Set`

```
List<String> first = ['101', '102', '103', '104', '105'];
List<String> second = ['101', '102', '103'];
List<String> result = Set.of(first).difference(Set.of(second)).toList()
print(result); // [104, 105]
```